# How do I read one line for a .txt file in c#?

Tags: c#, passwords

I am trying to make a password database with a sign in feature and register feature. I have got the register feature to work by saving Name, surname, email, and password into a .txt file, Howvever, I cannot make the program read one line and then check to see if the user input matches the password that is in the .txt file.
Here is what im working with so far.

```
//reading from file

int counter = 0;

private void Enter_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // makes a new file called password.txt
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("password.txt");

    string Line = "";
    //this reads all lines in the .txt file 
    while ((Line = sr.ReadLine())!=null)
    {
        //loops through each line.
        counter++;
        break;
    }
}
```

I want the while loop to only look at a line and then for the username i want to check for another line and verify that the username is correct.

```
counter++;

break;
```

I want this to go through the first line then break and that first line. I am working in visual studio using the Form Application.

Comment: **Never** store passwords as plain text. Use e.g. hash values instead.

Comment: @dymanoid is correct but that isn't what the question is about really OP wants help reading in stuff line by line

Comment: @Ethan - can you give us an example of what 1 line if your text file looks like please

Comment: Use [`File.ReadLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_ReadLines_System_String_) to read a line at a time. You can use `string line = File.ReadLines(filename).First()` to get just the first line.

Comment: @Dave, this is the reason I posted it as a comment, not as an answer. Maybe, the OP will re-think their solution, so the question will become irrelevant.

Comment: @dymanoid Yes all I want is to read one line, then the program checks the value against the user input. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you change 'while' to 'if'? And delete counter variable.

Comment: @Dave E.G if the .txt said Ethan (for the username ) and password1(for the password) (both on separate lines ) and then is checks that against the user input

Comment: how you are storing data after registration of a user?? and from that file, you to need to verify for login??

Comment: @D-johnAnshani yes, I'm just storing it in a .txt file (this is after the user registration) and yes i want to verify the login from that txt file

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statements without using the loop, but you have to do it manually.

For example:

```
//reading from file

int counter = 0;

private void Enter_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // makes a new file called password.txt
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("password.txt");

    string usr = "";
    string pass = "";

    pass = sr.ReadLine();
    if(pass != null)
    {
        //You get the password here now you can do the logic
    }
    else
    {
        //There is no line should throw an exception for instance
    }

    //Now lets get the username
    usr = sr.ReadLine();
    if(usr != null)
    {
        //You get the usr here
    }
    else
    {
        //There is no 2nd line should throw an exception for instance
    }

}
```

Comment: So the If (pass!=null) will get the password from the line of the .txt and the in the parentheses i can check to see if it matches?

Comment: Actually the  "pass = sr.ReadLine();" will get the password and the if condition will check if there is the line in the textfile, if there is a line then you can check inside or not if it matches for the user input or not.

Comment: What I am not really sure is what happen if you call sr.ReadLine() again if the previous one returns null. I think it would throw an exception but I am not really sure. Thats why I recommend you to throw an exception in the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("password.txt");
string user;
while((user = sr.ReadLine()) != null)  
{  
    string password;
    if ((password = sr.ReadLine()) == null) {
        // TODO: Throw some exception for example Illegal State.
    }
    if (string.Equals(user, #user)) {
        if (string.Equals(password , #password)) {
            sr.Close();
            // SUCCESS
        } else {
            // WRONG PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
sr.Close();
// WRONG USER
```

Comment: How my txt file is, is that the password is on the 9th line of the document, then the username is on the 7th and then I want it to read from those lines and i can validate the user and password

Comment: the normal way would be to use an other kind of format eg. xml, there are plenty of libarys out there. if not, just read all the lines of a block at once, parse them and check them

Answer (score 0):

You can read first one line than can iterate over it one by one.

```
int counter = 0;

private void Enter_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // makes a new file called password.txt
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("password.txt");

    string Line = sr.ReadLine();
    //this reads all chars in the line 
    foreach (var ch in Line)
    {
        //loops through each char.
        counter++;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you just want the length then you can use `Line.length`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the way you're inserting data.

Try to insert tab (\t) between the values and end the record by (\n) so that you can read entire file and use String.Split('\n') which will give you individual record and again split single record by String.Split('\t') to get username and password combinations..

Then you can have logic to validate credentials

Comment: What does the string.split function do ?

Comment: It will split the string by the char you have specified  as parameter in the argument.
http://csharp.net-informations.com/string/csharp-string-split.htm

here is a good example..